# Home Directory Permissions - Google Cloud Compute

Tags: centos, ssh, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I've setup a Linux (Centos) instance on Google Cloud Compute, I've also setup SSH as described here - https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-to-instance. I and can now connect using Filezilla to the specific user directory but I now cant get access to the home directory - I get a permissions denied error.

Does anyone know how I can change the permissions so I can edit/get access to the files in the home directory?

Comment: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/System_Administrators_Guide/s1-FTP.html *If you want local users to be able to access their home directories through FTP, which is the default setting on Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7, the `ftp_home_dir` Boolean option needs to be set to `1`.*

Comment: If you were able to solve this with @HBruijn's recommendation, you can post the self answer here for other community members who may be seeing this same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Posting @HBruijn comment as an answer, which seems to be the solution:

access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Lin‌​ux/… If you want local users to be able to access their home directories through FTP, which is the default setting on Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7, the `ftp_home_dir` Boolean option needs to be set to `1`.